# Setting WebBrowser.DocumentText = file.html?

Tags: c#, browser

Is there a way I can set a WebBrowser.DocumentText to a file without reading the file, setting its contents to a string variable then setting WebBrowser.DocumentText to that string variable? I wouldn't mind writing the code so much, it just seems like something that should be possible without it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean "not reading the file yourself"? Although these samples include "reading the file yourself", they are pretty simple:

```
browser.DocumentStream = new FileStream("file.html", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
```

or

```
browser.DocumentText = File.ReadAllText("file.html")
```

Comment: Sorry, I can be vague sometimes.  I meant reading it line by line in like a loop, but that requires a bit of code..

Answer (score 0):

You can read the file into a string and the set the property.

Note what MSDN says about it:

> When you set this property, the WebBrowser control automatically navigates to the about:blank URL before loading the specified text. This means that the Navigating, Navigated, and DocumentCompleted events occur when you set this property, and the value of the Url property is no longer meaningful.

But if you do this, you might as well use a `FileStream` pointing to the file in question and set the `DocumentStream` to it.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you can read the stream and set it to the [DocumentStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentstream.aspx) property.

An alternative is to set the [Url](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.url.aspx) property using a file url:

```
webBrowser.Url = new Url(@"file://C:\file.html");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`Navigate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/40x214wa.aspx) method.

```
WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowse();
//Put it on a form 
wb.Navigate(filePath);
```

File path will need to be of the form `file://server/filename.ext` or `file://C:/path/filename.ext`.